# CSS gradient issue (page break)

Tags: html, css, gradient

I want to use a gradient throughout the page (top to bottom) but my current gradient completes halfway down the page where my text div ends and then starts again... 
You can see it at codepen.io: https://codepen.io/pprunesquallor/pen/zwapGQ?editors=1100
My codepen uses Bootstrap 4, if that's of any relevance.

I hope I don't need to paste the entire HTML/CSS as there's already quite a lot of it. Here's just the gradient part:

```
body {
background: #00001e;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #F5981F , #5D82B3);
background: linear-gradient(to top, #F5981F , #5D82B3);
```

Comment: add `min-jeight:100vh;margin:0;` to your `body` tag, it will then spray at least on the whole height of the window if there is too litlle content to stretch it

Comment: the min-height:100vh does this https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KmexKe Or give another bg to html  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WjygbM when a single background is set to body or html, it is drawn on html , if html is set to an height, gradient will repeat passed this height . if you give a bg to html, body bg will be drawn in body

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` does currently not spread to the full page height but rather depends its size on its content height. To achieve a fully stretched background you might consider adding height:100% to you `html` element.

Furthermore, a `background-attachment: fixed` in your body CSS helps to fix errors on small browser windows.

Comment: Thank you! I added 100% height to html as well as body.

Comment: @PerryPrunesquallor I added another hint to my answer, to fix even more errors...